# How do I make a common function work for a clicked event only in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two fields password and password again. I want to make show and hide password on each field but clicking on one field's show icon should not show value of another field.
I have used common function for both onClick handler.
My fields are-

```
              <div className='form-group'>
                <input
                  type={toggle ? 'text' : 'password'}
                  placeholder='Password'
                />
                <i class='fas fa-eye-slash' onClick={showPassword}></i>
              </div>
              <div className='form-group'>
                <input
                  type={toggle ? 'text' : 'password'}
                  placeholder='Retype Password'
                />
                <i class='fas fa-eye-slash' onClick={showPassword}></i>
              </div>
```

> My state declaration is-

```
 const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false)
```

> My function is-

```
function showPassword() {
    setToggle(!toggle)
  }
```

After doing this, whenever I click on one field show icon, both field's password are revealed and vice-versa.

Comment: Could be you are using the same state for both field? Is not so clear what is the problem, but in case you should use two different state

Comment: Keep status of each field separately on the state [or] create 2 states for managing these two field status.

Comment: @AlfredoLipari I want to do it using only one state. It is not feasible to declare new state for every fields all the time particularly when you have large number of similar fields.

Comment: @SarunUK  Could you please tell me how do I implement your first suggestion?

Comment: Created a sample demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-poitras-unvv7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Instead of true and false you can use different values, in this case the default value is:
(Is not very clean and I didnt try but It makes sense)

```
 const [toggle, setToggle] = useState("password")
```

then you pass to your function what are you clicking in that moment

```
  <div className='form-group'>
                <input
                  type={toggle === "password1" ? 'text' : 'password'}
                  placeholder='Password'
                />
                <i class='fas fa-eye-slash' onClick={showPassword("password1"}></i>
              </div>
              <div className='form-group'>
                <input
                  type={toggle === "password2" ? 'text' : 'password'}
                  placeholder='Retype Password'
                />
                <i class='fas fa-eye-slash' onClick={showPassword("password2"}></i>
              </div>
```

```
function showPassword(text){
   
   text === "password1" ? "password1" : "password2"
    //if text is already the same restore the default value
   text === toogle && "password" 
    setToggle(text)
  }
```